Report viewer Visual studio 2022 cant select report to show
I have Visual Studio 2022 and couldnt get reportviewer to work, finally after a lot of time and search on the web, i got it to show in my toolbox.
But now im trying to select the report to show on the winform and it doesnt show anything, only Docking parent container option.
Any idea how to get it to work?

Thanks!
No code is shown in this part

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
